# Why am I getting ArgumentOutOfRangeException in Lists?

Tags: c#, .net, list

I am using List of Lists in my project. When i run program i get `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. But there is no range specified in list. 
I declared list like this:

```
public static List<List<string>> list = new List<List<string>>();
```

Now i want to add my name in the first "list" which is in the List of lists.

```
list[0].Add("Hussam"); //Here i get ArgumentOutOfRange Exception.
```

What should I do now?

Comment: you need to add an item to the list.... right now when you create it, there are NO items in the list. you need to do: list.Add(new List<string>("hussam")). without any items...the length is 0 and therefore you cannot access the collection via indexer and even if you did... you may not index the correct valid element

Answer (score 11):

> But there is no range specified in list

No, there's an *index* specified (as an argument), and that's what's out of range. Look at your code:

```
list[0].Add("Hussam");
```

That's trying to use the first list in `list` - but is `list` is empty, there *is* no first element. The range of valid arguments to the indexer is empty, basically.

So first you want:

```
list.Add(new List<string>());
```

Now `list[0]` will correctly refer to your empty `List<string>`, so you can add `"Hussam"` to it.

Answer (score 2):

You want to add an item to the first item in an empty list... That isn't going to work. First, add the list inside the other list:

```
public static List<List<string>> list = new List<List<string>>();

List<string> innerList = new List<string>();
list.Add(innerList);

innerList.Add("Hussam");
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access `list[0]` as there is no item at index 0. The list is empty.

You need to add a new List like this:

```
list.Add(new List<string> { "Hussam" });
```

or, assign a list to index 0 and then add to it as per your posted code:

```
list.Add(new List<string>());
list[0].Add("Hussam");
```

If you don't always know if the list will be be empty or not you can use `FirstOrDefault` (a LINQ method) to check if there is any entry at index 0 and assign one if not, otherwise use the existing inner list:

```
var innerList = list.FirstOrDefault();
if (innerList == null)
{
    innerList = new List<string>();
    list.Add(innerList);
 }

 innerList.Add("Hussam");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating a list of a list? Wouldn't List suffice? What is happening here is the inner list is not being initialized.

```
list.Add(new List<string>());
list[0].Add("Jimmy");
```

Comment: Why do you think OP doesn't need an inner list? Maybe he does.

Comment: ...Which isn't an answer.

Comment: And I posted the answer follows.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your nested list hasn't been initialized, with *anything*.

So, calling the first item of the nested list is correctly telling you there is nothing in it.

To verify:

```
int superlistCounter = 1;
int sublistCounter = 1;

foreach(var sublist in list)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Now in List #" + superlistCounter);
   foreach(var item in sublist)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("List item #" + sublistCounter + ": " + item)
   }
}
```

The output will be:

```
Now in List #1
```

It sounds like you're expecting:

```
Now in List #1
List Item #1: Hussam
```

To fix this, simply initialize your list!

```
public static List<List<string>> list = new List<List<string>>();

// ...

List<string> subList1 = new List<string>();
list.Add(subList1);

subList1.Add("Hussam");
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case ocurred an exception because you tried acess an index which not exists, then you must add an inner initial list, which could be done follows:

```
list.Add(new new List<string>());
```

Or, if you want add an first name directly:

```
list.Add(new new List<string>(){"Hussam"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so first, you have to understand that the "index" only comes after the value has been declared. Lists behave different. They are not like arrays. You get the index in which you want to store the item and when you do that, you use the code `array[index] = value;`.

But in a `List`, to give a value to a completely new item, you use the method `Add(value)`.

So here's a reminder: *Systems.Collections.Generic.List<> has nothing to do with array[ ]s*